# Split string using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to split the following type of string using the `String.prototype.split()` method:

```
"#flat flat#flat #flat# flat#"
```

The condition for splitting is '#' positioned at the beginning of the word + words that follow it , until next such '#'. For example the string  above should be splitted like that:

```
["#flat flat#flat","#flat# flat#"]
```

I tried a lot of different variants but none of them is correct.

Comment: Can you share regex/code you have tried?

Comment: can you share some more sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I was wondering why you removed your answer.

Comment: @Rajesh I think more details are required. My answer may work for input/output shared by OP, but not sure if it will suffice as per explanation given `until next such '#'` which is a bit unclear.

Comment: I mean that ['#with some folowing words'] should be an item of an array, these words also may contain hashtags, but if '#' places inside or at the end of the word it should be ignored

Comment: @W.Larsen can you share more inputs and outputs sample?

Comment: `"#flat flat#flat #flat# flat#".split(/(?!^)(?=\B#\b)/)` -> `["#flat flat#flat ", "#flat# flat#"]`

Comment: @W.Larsen: Are there any Unicode hashtags to consider? If yes, a `\b`/`\B` solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a Little on what you call a word (or better what Ends a word), but i take it as a word is separated by a space character.

In this case, this code gives you the desired Output: `myString.split(/ #|^#|#$/)`.
It Outputs as a list that contains an empty string at the start and at the beginning which is may be a bit uncomfortable; to remove this you would extend the Piece of code to: `myString.split(/ #|^#|#$/).filter(match=>match!=='')`. This removes This Returns a list with these empty strings removed.

Hope this helps!